# UWP - Proper way of passing parameters between pages

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

Suppose I want to pass one object (reference) through several pages. I can navigate and pass parameters via `Frame.Navigate(typeof(FirstPage), object)`. But how to pass the reference back on back press properly?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Parameter is SomeClass) {
      this.someObject = (SomeClass)e.Parameter;
   }
   else {
      this.someObject = new SomeClass();
   }

   SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
   SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed;

   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}


private void OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e) {
   // This is the missing line!
   Frame.Navigate(typeof(FirstPage), this.someObject);
}
```

But when I press back button it goes back to the `FirstPage` `OnNavigatedTo` with no parameter, and then back to the `SecondPage` `OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed` and then back to `FirstPage` `OnNavigatedTo` with filled parameter.

Could you please advice me some better approach?

Answer (score 3):

In your back handler, don't navigate forwards again, just call `GoBack` -- and it's typically easier if you handle that at a global level rather than at a page level.

You can store your application state (the things you want to persist across page navigations) in global / static objects, or you could directly modify the object that was passed from the initial navigation (if the calling page still has a reference, it will be able to see the changes).

I would consider doing a search for "MVVM Windows Apps" and looking at some of the results to learn about a common way of building XAML apps.